# (AllocMem and GetMem) Failure

Tags: delphi, winapi

There is a maximum number of pointers that can be allocated? I'm working on a function that allocates various pointers to various records. After an amount (x) not calculated, the AllocMem function allocates a pointer overwriting the existing pointers. Anyone have a tips?

```
function NewObject(ID: Integer): boolean;
Var P: PNewObject;
begin

P:= Allocmem(SizeOf(TNewObject));
P^.ID:= ID;
...
```

Pointers that were allocated will only be released when the program close!

Comment: From documentation, [System.AllocMem](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AllocMem) `If there is not enough memory available to allocate the block, an EOutOfMemory exception is raised`.

Comment: In other words, `AllocMem()` does not "overwrite existing pointers".  That being said, for record/class types, try using `New()` instead of `AllocMem()` or `GetMem() directly (unless `TNewObject` consists of only POD type members).

Answer (score 6):

There is no maximum number of pointers that can be allocated. Dynamic memory allocation may fail if the memory manager is unable to find a suitable block of memory. In that scenario `EOutOfMemory` is raised.

> After an amount (x) not calculated, the AllocMem function allocates a pointer overwriting the existing pointers.

No, that is not the case. The dynamic memory allocation functions will never return a block of memory that is already in use.

It sounds as though your program allocates but never deallocates. That might be a tenable approach if you have a garbage collector at hand, but this is not the case for you. Perhaps you need to consider deallocating when you are done with the memory.